# How to distinguish between click events on paper-buttons created with dom-repeat template?

Tags: polymer

I have a series of paper buttons inside a dom repeat polymer element.

```
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myitems}}">
    <p>name: <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    <paper-button on-click="makeSomething">makeSomething</paper-button>
    </p>
  </template>
```

In the script section, I implemented the makeSomething function of the fired event. How can I distinguish between a click on the first item and a click on the second one?

I tried to set custom attributes on the paper button, e.g.

```
<paper-button on-click="makeSomething" name="{{item.name}}">makeSomething</paper-button>
```

but the getAttribute on the target doesn't seem to work with attribute name...
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the ['Handling events in dom-repeat templates'](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#handling-events) section in the documentation. Here is the example they give:

```
<dom-module id="simple-menu">

  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" id="menu" items="{{menuItems}}">
        <div>
          <span>{{item.name}}</span>
          <span>{{item.ordered}}</span> 
          <button on-click="order">Order</button>
        </div>
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'simple-menu',
      ready: function() {
        this.menuItems = [
            { name: "Pizza", ordered: 0 },
            { name: "Pasta", ordered: 0 },
            { name: "Toast", ordered: 0 }
        ];
      },
      order: function(e) {
        var model = e.model;
        model.set('item.ordered', model.item.ordered+1);
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```